# Converting htaccess to web.config causing 500 error and I can't see, why?

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, windows-server-2008

There I'm really stuck here, and its driving me insane. Ive searched all over but I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm moving an application that was previously on a windows server with ISAPI_ModRewrite so this worked with htaccess, I'm trying to move this to a windows-server 2008 server which I cant have ISAPI installed on as its a shared hosting environment.

Below is what I'm trying to do but this is just returning a 500 internal server error any ideas what I'm doing wrong? this is the htaccess code I'm trying to convert...

```
# PRODUCT PAGE
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/(.*)/? /prodpage.asp?productid=$1 [L]

# OTHER PAGES

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1.asp [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$ /$1.asp?pricerange=$2-$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([a-z])/$ /$1.asp?pricerange=$2-$3&sort=$4

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

And this is my web.config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Product Page" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([0-9]*)/(.*)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="prodpage.asp?productid={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Other Page1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^/]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Other Page2" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp?pricerange={R:2}-{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Other Page3" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([a-z])/$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp?pricerange={R:2}-{R:3}&sort={R:4}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed this sorry, thought i would post my answer for those that may need help in future.

i needed to replace the & symbol with & as its xml. Thanks anyway :)